# Resample hourly TimeSeries with certain starting hour

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample a TimeSeries in daily (exactly 24 hours) frequence starting at a certain hour.

Like:

```
index = date_range(datetime(2012,1,1,17), freq='H', periods=60)

ts = Series(data=[1]*60, index=index)

ts.resample(rule='D', how='sum', closed='left', label='left')
```

Result i get:

```
2012-01-01  7
2012-01-02 24
2012-01-03 24
2012-01-04  5
Freq: D
```

Result i wish:

```
2012-01-01 17:00:00 24
2012-01-02 17:00:00 24
2012-01-03 17:00:00 12
Freq: D
```

Some weeks ago you could pass `'24H'` to the `freq` argument and it worked totally fine.
But now it combines `'24H'` to `'1D'`.

Was I using a bug with `'24H'` which is fixed now?
And how can i get the wished result in a efficient and pythonic (or pandas) way back?

versions:

- python 2.7.3
- pandas 0.9.0rc1 (but doesn't work in 0.8.1, too)
- numpy 1.6.1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Resample](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#resampling) has an `base` argument which covers this case:

```
ts.resample(rule='24H', closed='left', label='left', base=17).sum()
```

Output:

```
2012-01-01 17:00:00    24
2012-01-02 17:00:00    24
2012-01-03 17:00:00    12
Freq: 24H
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't understand that parameter documentation and thought it was added for upsampling cases.

Comment: @MaM I agree with you. The documentation in this case needs a good example.

Answer (score 8):

**2021 Update: `base` is deprecated since version 1.1.0: The new arguments that you should use are ‘offset’ or ‘origin’.**

```py
df.resample('24H',
 origin=datetime(2012,1,1,17) # <--  ADD THIS
).sum()
```

**New in version 1.1.0**

**origin**{‘epoch’, ‘start’, ‘start_day’}, Timestamp or str, default ‘start_day’
The timestamp on which to adjust the grouping. The timezone of origin must match the timezone of the index. If a timestamp is not used, these values are also supported:

- ‘epoch’: origin is 1970-01-01
- ‘start’: origin is the first value of    the timeseries
- ‘start_day’: origin is the first day at midnight of    the timeseries

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Update: for dataframes**

Use the `base` keyword as referred in the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

[image: base description of documentation]

Code example:

```
df.resample(pd.Timedelta('24 hours'), # or '24H'
 base=17 # <--  ADD THIS
).sum()
```