# groupby date using other start time than midnight

Tags: pandas, group-by, timestamp, resampling

I am aggregating some data by date.

```
for dt,group in df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.date):
      # do stuff
```

Now, I would like to do the same, but without using midnight as time offset.
Still, I would like to use groupby, but e.g. in 6AM-6AM bins.
Is there any better solution than a dummy column?
unfortunately, resample as discussed in

[Resample daily pandas timeseries with start at time other than midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374736/resample-daily-pandas-timeseries-with-start-at-time-other-than-midnight)
[Resample hourly TimeSeries with certain starting hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579150/resample-hourly-timeseries-with-certain-starting-hour)

does not work, as I do need to apply any resampling/aggregation function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, for example, subtract the offset before grouping:

```
for dt, group in df.groupby(df.timestamp.sub(pd.to_timedelta('6H')).dt.date):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a `base` argument for `resample` or `pd.Grouper` that is meant to handle this situation. There are many ways to accomplish this, pick whichever you feel is more clear.

- '1D' frequency with `base=0.25`
- '24h' frequency with `base=6`
- '1440min' frequency with `base=360`

## Code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='10min', periods=200)})

df.resample(on='timestamp', rule='1D', base=0.25).timestamp.agg(['min', 'max'])
#df.resample(on='timestamp', rule='24h', base=6).timestamp.agg(['min', 'max'])
#df.resample(on='timestamp', rule=f'{60*24}min', base=60*6).timestmap.agg(['min', 'max'])
```

---

```
                                    min                 max
timestamp                                                  
2009-12-31 06:00:00 2010-01-01 00:00:00 2010-01-01 05:50:00  #[Dec31 6AM - Jan1 6AM)
2010-01-01 06:00:00 2010-01-01 06:00:00 2010-01-02 05:50:00  #[Jan1 6AM - Jan2 6AM)
2010-01-02 06:00:00 2010-01-02 06:00:00 2010-01-02 09:10:00  #[Jan2 6AM - Jan3 6AM)
```

---

For completeness, `resample` is a convenience method and is in all ways the same as `groupby`. If for some reason you absolutely cannot use `resample` you could do:

```
for dt, gp in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='24h', base=6)):
    ...
```

which is equivalent to

```
for dt, gp in df.resample(on='timestamp', rule='24h', base=6):
    ...
```

Comment: i can not use resample, as mentioned in the question

Comment: @00__00__00 if you can use `groupby` you can use `resample`... `for dt, gp in df.resample(on='timestamp', rule=f'{60*24}min', base=60*6):` It's just a convenience method really and to my knowledge is identical to a groupby.

Comment: That is, it's identical to the following uglier groupby call: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq=f'{60*24}min', base=60*6))`