# How to do resample of intraday timeseries data with dateOffset in Pandas/Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I'm dealing with futures data, where the current day starts before 00:00:00. I need to do resampling of 1 minute data to 1 hour data, taking into account the date offset. Let's see an example:

df1 - 1min data

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close
2005-09-06 17:27:00  1234.75  1234.75  1234.75  1234.75
2005-09-06 17:28:00  1234.75  1234.75  1234.75  1234.75
2005-09-06 17:29:00  1234.75  1234.75  1234.75  1234.75
2005-09-06 17:30:00  1234.75  1234.75  1234.50  1234.50
2005-09-06 18:01:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.25  1234.50
2005-09-06 18:02:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.50  1234.50
2005-09-06 18:03:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.50  1234.50
2005-09-06 18:04:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.50  1234.50
2005-09-06 18:05:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.25  1234.25
```

This is what happens with a regular resample:

```
conversion = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}

In [77]: normal_resample = df1.resample(rule='60Min', how=conversion)
In [78]: normal_resample
Out[79]: 
                        Open     High      Low    Close
2005-09-06 17:00:00  1234.75  1234.75  1234.50  1234.50
2005-09-06 18:00:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.25  1234.25
```

This is the desired output accounting for the offset:

```
conversion = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}

In [77]: offset_resample = df1.resample(rule='60Min', how=conversion) + offset:18:00
In [78]: offset_resample
Out[79]: 
                        Open     High      Low    Close
2005-09-06 17:00:00  1234.75  1234.75  1234.50  1234.50
2005-09-07 18:00:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.25  1234.25
```

Notice how what I want is specify that the new day starts at '18:00:00', not at midnight.

What have I done:  I have a formula that includes the offset, resampling to daily data, but I don't know how to adapt it for intraday resampling.

```
def resample_day(df):
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
    df = df.between_time('18:00', '16:00', include_start=True, include_end=True)
    proxy = df.index + pd.DateOffset(hours=6)  # This is the piece that does the trick
    result = df.groupby(proxy.date).agg(
        {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'})
    result = result.reindex(columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
    return result
```

Also, what is [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579150/resample-hourly-timeseries-with-certain-starting-hour), doesn't work, for me at least.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: +1 for that resample trick, very nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add on a day (if it the time is past 5pm):

```
In [11]: df1.index.time > datetime.time(17)
Out[11]: array([False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [12]: df1.index + np.where((df1.index.time > datetime.time(17)), pd.offsets.Day(1).nanos, 0)
Out[12]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2005-09-06 17:00:00, 2005-09-07 18:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: 60T, Timezone: None
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems like a good workaround, but I get this crazy error: File "<ipython-input-10-01d9195a0849>", line 1, in <module>
    df1.index + np.where((df1.index.time > datetime.time(17)), pd.offsets.Day(1).nanos, 0)

  File "C:\Users\Hernan\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.py", line 619, in __add__
    raise TypeError(other)

TypeError: [             0              0 86400000000000 ...,              0
              0              0]

Comment: are you using older version of pandas / numpy ? Perhaps try: `pd.to_datetime(df1.index.values + np.where((df1.index.time > datetime.time(17)), pd.offsets.Day(1).nanos, 0))` or possibly `df1.index.values.astype('int64')`

Comment: pd.__version__'0.14.0', numpy.version.version '1.8.1'

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df1.index.values + np.where((df1.index.time > datetime.time(17)), pd.offsets.Day(1).nanos, 0)) gives me an empty df. And df1.index.values.astype('int64')...don't know how to use this.

Comment: @hernanavella interesting, perhaps this was fixed in 0.14.1. So the above the aim is to convert the datetime to int64 in nanoseconds and then add it to the datetime64 as nanoseconds (astype('int64')) then wrap in to_datetime to get nanoseconds to datetime64. You have to set the result (a new DatetimeIndex) to df1.index if that wasn't clear i.e. df1.index = pd.to_datetime(...)